# what is deep_ping

Tags: java, web-applications, servlets, ping

I am not sure if this is the correct forum to ask this but i am not sure where to ask either. So here is my question:

what does "deep ping" mean. I tried google but still did not get any information about it. Also who does deep ping mean in web servlet`s context. Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave some context. For example, where did you hear the term?

Comment: Come on, the question's been around for 2 hours and nobody's answered that it's the gerund form of the verb "to deep"?

Comment: But seriously, close-voters: it's a perfectly valid question, with a perfectly valid (and accepted) answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure it's the "official definition" if there is such a thing, but I've head "deep ping" used about functionality that allows you to (in contrast to a regular ping) send a message to the server that ***passes through as much of the webstack as possible*** before returning an "ok" response.

As an example, you can make a `ping` transaction that passes from the network straight down the stack to the database and there does a dummy select to read the `ok` from a dummy table and return that result. That allows you to (in contrast to a "normal ping" that tests only the network) have confidence that *all layers* in the application including the database are actually alive.

Comment: Ping is Packet Interner Groping Protocol, which is used for checking the 2 way connectivity, it doesn't and will never check for any DB....

Comment: @KumarVivekMitra Yes, a `deep ping` is not related to an `ICMP Echo Request` in any way except the name. The "ping" part just refers to the "I send a request and get a response if you're ok" part.

Comment: So it essentially is a test for all the connections used within the web stack i.e the connection with other web services and connection with DB? not just the front end host connection

Comment: @maverik Yes, as simple a test as possible (no complex logic) that tests that the whole (or as much as possible of the) stack is alive and well.

Answer (score 0):

**-** `Ping` is one of the most basic and useful network commands. It sends request to networked computer and waits for response. It’s easy to ping single PC but it’s pain to ping dozens (or even hundreds) of them.

**-** The process of `Pinging` the `entire Subnet` which can have N nos of PCs are known as `Deep Ping`. Network scanners are usually used to do this....

Comment: I don't know why this answer has negative upvotes.
Since there is no definite definition, so at network level this definition sounds correct, whereas, at the infrastructure level, Joachim Isaksson answer sounds correct to me.