# What is the difference between a 'shallow' and 'deep' ping?

Tags: networking, ping

So as a fairly new (out-in-the-world-working) developer I'm not unfamiliar to the concept of pinging as it was taught to me in uni and I've used it in various small assignments I've encountered before.

My understanding of it is **determining whether another host is present and responsive on a network**.

I've implemented in Java (the language i'm most comfortable in) some code similar to the one below when wanting to achieve pinging:

```
try {
    String ip = "127.192.199.01";
    InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
    System.out.println("Send ping-request to: " + ip);
    if (inet.isReachable(5000)){
        System.out.println(ip + " is reachable.");
    } else {
        System.out.println(ip + " NOT reachable.");
    }
} catch ( Exception e ) {
  System.out.println("Exception:" + e.getMessage()); 
}
```

However I pretty new to the concept of 'shallow' and 'deep' pinging which is something I've encountered at my current workplace.

So far though I've been able to figure out that deep pinging is basically about testing that all connections are alive and working while testing functionality through as much of a webstack as possible.

Got that from: [what is deep_ping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464540/what-is-deep-ping)

**My question is:**
What does a shallow ping do then?
And what is then the *main difference (if any) between a shallow and deep ping*?

Comment: I think you should wait at least a day before you accept an answer. That could make more people visit the question, and even give you more quality answers. (Also, it could give you more rep, as side effect)

Comment: @Shirkam Aha,thanks for the tip. Still pretty new at this so appreciate you pointing that out. 

Will refrain from accepting for atleast a day

Answer (score 2):

Shallow ping works by sending one or more (ICMP/ICMP6) Echo Request packets to the host and only tests if the network is working i.e. if the host is reachable from your machine.

Deep pinging works by testing the application. How the deep ping is implemented is up to the developer but it could be via a "status" endpoint which responds with the current application status, or another similar interface (as described in the link you already mentioned).

As per your link, deep pinging can also mean testing an entire subnet or testing other protocols than the standard Echo Request.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you are performing host availability test on different OSI layers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)

A ping how you know it is performed on the transport layer, where a single packet is sent to the other machine and the OS responds with another packet.

In that case you do not know if there is ANY application running on that node other than the clean OS.

Going further up in the OSI layers you can then perform tests on you business logic like calling APIs of your HTTP based REST API

Answer (score 1):

My gut feeling is that "shallow ping" means a ping performed using the standard ICMP request (the well known ping command we know about), a "deep ping" is trying to access the actual remote service by opening a socket on a given port and see if you get any answer

Answer (score 0):

How I can interpret it:

Shallow ping : The host is available, port on which service is exposed is accepting. (more like telnet)

Deep ping : You are actually hitting one of the service and getting an expected response back.

Again, these are more like custom terms, not an actually defined standard.